# Unable to get the dimensions of uploaded file in php

Tags: php, file-upload, getimagesize

Need to get the dimensions of the uploaded files such as width, height, size, etc. I tried using `getimagesize()`  , but that does not works. I get an error,

```
Warning: getimagesize(C:/wamp/www/KSHRC/uploads/): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\KSHRC\registration\multi_fileupload.php on line 31
```

and

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\KSHRC\registration\multi_fileupload.php on line 31
```

Here's the code,

```
for($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);$i++)
{
    $root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/KSHRC/uploads/";    
    $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];
    echo $size = getimagesize($root.$filename);
}
```

Please help me..

Comment: I guess you should loop over `$_FILES['userfile']` & not `$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']`. Can you post `var_dump($_FILES['userfile'])` ?

Comment: `$_FILES` refers to your file into tmp folder. you have to move it first in your desired folder

Comment: But when i echo the $filename it returns the proper filename..

Comment: @user3300295: Actually i need to check dimensions before uploading takes place

Comment: @sonans width and height?

Comment: @Rikesh: It's showing ,
    'name' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'rronline1.jpg' (length=13)
  'type' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
  'tmp_name' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\php65E7.tmp' (length=23)
  'error' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 0
  'size' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 173087

Answer (score 1):

you have to move the file from tmp to your desired folder first then you can get the image size by using your function `getimagesize`

```
for($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);$i++)
{
    $root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/KSHRC/uploads/";    
    $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $root.$filename);
    echo $size = getimagesize($root.$filename);
}
```

**Update**

you can also get the file size by `$_FILES['userfile']['size']` Like this

```
$size = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
```

this will return size in bytes

**UPDATE 2**

```
$ARR_FILES = $_FILES['userfile'];

 for($i=0; $i < count($ARR_FILES);$i++)
    {
        $root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/KSHRC/uploads/";    
        $filename = $ARR_FILES[$i]['name'];
        $tmp_name = $ARR_FILES[$i]['tmp_name'];
        list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($tmp_name); 
       echo $width;
       echo $height;
    }
```

Comment: Is there a similar code to get the image width and height as for $_FILES['userfile']['size'];

Comment: no it will give the size in bytes only are you want to find the width and height of image?

Comment: user3300295: Yes, need to find width and height

Comment: thankyou! 
Replaced the code,
        `for($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);$i++)
        {
         list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i]); 
       echo $width;
        echo $height;
        }`